# How can arguments be passed to executable given for lldb in a VSCode launch.json file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang, lldb, vscode-debugger

I want to debug this command in VSCode:

```
myExecutable -f arg1 -g arg2 -e arg3
```

Notice the executable takes 3 arguments. When running this executable in lldb we need to use "--" to pass the arguments to the executable:

```
lldb myExecutable -- -f arg1 -g arg2 -e arg3
```

I need to find out how to pass these 3 arguments to the executable given to lldb through the launch.json file for VSCode.

**How the "args" JSON field should be properly defined for lldb to be able to debug the executable above with it?**

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(Launch) lldb",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [
            "-f arg1",
            "-g arg2",
            "-e arg3"
        ],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "lldb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/somepath/lldb-mi/build/src/lldb-mi"
    }
]
```

}

I am doing this in Linux Debian 11.

Answer (score 3):

The issue above was due to spaces in the arguments. Here is the JSON snippet that works. Notice how the flag and the actual argument goes separately.

```
    "args": [
        "-f",
        "arg1",
        "-e"
        "arg2",
        "-g",
        "arg3"
    ],
```